# XMLHttpRequest - sending files?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

On my forms submission I have:

```
var formData = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i < ctx.files.length; i++) {
            formData.append('file[]', ctx.files[i]);

        }
```

On my server side I just dump the $_POST.

I get:

```
array(1) {
 ["file"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
   string(17) "[object FileList]"
 }
}
```

It's coming through as a string, how can I get it as an array of files?

Here's the whole request:

```
var formData = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i < ctx.files.length; i++) {
            formData.append('file[]', ctx.files[i]);
            //formData.push(ctx.files[i]);
        }

        // now post a new XHR request
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/site-manager-gateway/add-content');
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log('all done: ' + xhr.status);
            } else {
                console.log('Something went terribly wrong...');
            }
        };

        xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: Show us your request too.

Comment: Added to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Missing things

Add this before send:
`xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");`

### Accessing the files

After that, the files can be access like this:

```
$count = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
   echo 'Uploaded File With FileName: '.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i].'<br/>';

}
```

### More Info: $_FILES variable

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

If you go to this link you will see that the `$_FILES` variable will be like this:

```
array(1) {
    ["upload"]=>array(5) {
        ["name"]=>array(3) {
            [0]=>string(9)"file0.txt"
            [1]=>string(9)"file1.txt"
            [2]=>string(9)"file2.txt"
        }
        ["type"]=>array(3) {
            [0]=>string(10)"text/plain"
            [1]=>string(10)"text/plain"
            [2]=>string(10)"text/plain"
        }
        ["tmp_name"]=>array(3) {
            [0]=>string(14)"/tmp/blablabla"
            [1]=>string(14)"/tmp/phpyzZxta"
            [2]=>string(14)"/tmp/phpn3nopO"
        }
        ["error"]=>array(3) {
            [0]=>int(0)
            [1]=>int(0)
            [2]=>int(0)
        }
        ["size"]=>array(3) {
            [0]=>int(0)
            [1]=>int(0)
            [2]=>int(0)
        }
    }
}
```

### "But...where are my files??"

Your files are located in a temporally folder (In linux, the default is /tmp).
The only way to recover your files from this temporally folder is using on each file the php function:

`move_uploaded_file`

Which according to the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php):

> "This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename
>   is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP
>   POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
>   filename given by destination.
>
> This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that
>   anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the
>   user, or even to other users on the same system."

### move_uploaded_file Usage

This is how you should do it. If you uploads directory is called "uploads" then:

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

And that will save all your files in the "/uploads" directory.